# How come nothing is appearing when I add if statements to my PHP code?

Tags: php, html

I am trying to make a form that echos out whatever the user inputs into the 'name' field, but, I cannot figure out why when I add an `if` statement, nothing in the code shows up.

Here is my `index.php` code:

```
<?

if (empty($_POST['name'])) {
echo "Hello world!";
}   else {
    echo "Hello $_POST['name']";

}
?>

<html>
<head>
    <?php include 'header.php'; ?>
</head>

<body>

<form action="index.php" method="post">
    <p>Name: <input type="text" name="name"></p>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Go">
</form>

</body>
<footer>
    <?php include 'footer.php'; ?>
</footer>
</html>
```

Comment: Maybe try changing the first line from `<?` to `<?php`?

Comment: You also shouldn't be directly putting `$_POST['name']` into a string like that. Use string concatenation or something similar.

Comment: if you want to enclose the $_POST[''] in quotes, put {} around the $_POST[] - viz: `"hello {$_POST['name']}"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The valid syntax for adding an array into echo is:

```
echo "Hello {$_POST['name']}";
```

Or concatenate it using:

```
echo "Hello " . $_POST['name'];
```

Reference: [echo](http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you enable errors while debugging:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

Problem, seems to be with php short tag `<?` which might not enabled, try using `<?php` or enable short tag in `php.ini`

Answer (score 0):

The page is reloading index.php with your form. change `<form action="index.php" method="post">` to `<form action="" method="post">`

Answer (score 0):

You can't echo array inside "" quotes.

Try this (var in {}):

```
echo "Hello {$_POST['name']}";
```

Or this (with string operator):

```
echo "Hello " . $_POST['name'];
```